# Horizontal menu CSS - replicate the menu of donebynone.com

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to replicate the menu of donebynone.com, but for `window resize` its not proper, can anyone help in the below code?

Please check code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/SjjUe/

Comment: Remember that warning you saw when you tried to post your question without any code and a link to jsFiddle? Yeah that. It's there for a reason. Not everyone can visit, or wants to visit, jsFiddle. Always post the relevant code in your question please.

Comment: Actually I was not able to post code here thats why thought to post code in jsfiddle.

Comment: can we talk related to question??

Comment: Well I havent fixed it but if you remove the padding-left: 44px; from the li css it makes it much closer to the desired result. Its just off by a little.

Comment: whatever this person is doing just encourage him! Everybody is not pro here! If somebody is learning ! Help them if they are asking questions! he is learning and he will be good if you encourage him!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your modified menu >> [Menu Resizable](http://jsfiddle.net/SjjUe/5/)

Static- `Better` Version >> [Not Resizable](http://jsfiddle.net/SjjUe/6/)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Eirenaios its working very fine for me.  (Menu Resizable)

Comment: Enjoy! Happy to help! :D

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, just right click near the menu and hit "Inspect Element". That should bring up a menu on the bottom with code in it. Just go through that and see if you find what you are looking for.

Comment: Ya i have tried that but it will fix on my system only. not for all browser and device.

Comment: You can edit and select the code by doing that. That's what I meant.